# VMware ESXi でゲスト OS インストール時にキーボードから = (イコール) が入力できない

Tags: linux, vmware

VMware ESXi の環境に Linux のゲスト OS (RHEL7.9) をインストールしようとしています。

仮想マシンを作成してインストールメディアから起動すると解像度がデフォルトのままなので、画面の一部が途切れてしまいます。起動直後にパラメータを変更することでインストール時の解像度を変更できるようですが、起動直後は (日本語キーボードでも) 英語配列になっているので、<kbd>^</kbd> の刻印があるキーを押しても `=` 記号が入力できません (なぜか `6` が入力される)。ちなみに、<kbd>@</kbd> を押した場合も `2` が入力されます。

ノート PC の問題かと思い、外付けキーボードを繋いでみましたが結果は変わりませんでした。

OS のインストーラさえ起動すれば正しく日本語配列として認識されるのですが、起動直後の画面で `=` を入力する方法、もしくは日本語配列に変更する方法はありますか？

**追記:**
なお、VirtualBox では英語配列の状態で <kbd>^</kbd> を押せば `=` が入力できることを確認しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のページを見る限り、英語以外のキーボード配列で問題が発生する場合があるようです。

[Some non-English keyboard layout keys do not work as expected in the VMware HTML Console 2.0 (2148037)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2148037)

> To work around this issue, use the VMRC console.

ページ末尾に記載のあるワークアラウンドとして紹介されていた [VMware Remote Console](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/downloads/details?downloadGroup=VMRC1201&productId=876) をダウンロードしインストール後、vShere Client の画面から「コンソール」→「リモートコンソールを起動」することで、今回の問題を回避することができました。